# Extract string between two - from informatica expression transformation

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

My Oracle database is having data in one column as below. What is required is only the data between '-'.

Hello - 12345 - Bye
Hai - 5678 - Try
and so on.

My output should be 
12345
5678

I need Informatica expression transformation Query for the above scebnario.

Comment: if one of the below answers resolves your issues please accept one

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like this**

`REPLACESTR(1,YOUR_COLUMN,'-',' ')`

Find more sample

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/transformation-language-reference/functions/replacestr.html

Answer (score 0):

Another answer would be to use the `Java Transformation` and split that string on '-' this will be useful if you need to access the elements after you remove the "-" character.

```java
String myStr = "Hello - 12345 - Bye Hai - 5678 - Try and so on.";
String[] myArr = myStr.split("-");
```

so now

```java
myArr[0] == Hello
myArr[1] == 12345
myArr[2] == Bye Hai
...
```